# WPF window in separate desktop works in Win10, not in Win7

Tags: c#, wpf, win32gui

I'm trying to open a WPF window on a separate desktop. In Windows 10, the code below works as expected and shows this Window:

[image]

However, in Windows 7, the text is not shown and the Windows wallpaper bleeds through:

[image]

The code is pretty straight forward, I think:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    const uint GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]   static extern IntPtr GetThreadDesktop(uint dwThreadId);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]   static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(string desktopName, IntPtr device, IntPtr deviceMode, uint flags, uint accessMask, IntPtr attributes);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]   static extern bool SetThreadDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]   static extern bool CloseDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]   static extern bool SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var btn = new Button() { Content = "Open secure desktop" };
        btn.Click += (s, e) => SecureDialog();
        var win = new Window() { Content = btn };
        new Application().Run(win);
    }

    static void SecureDialog()
    {
        var hOldDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
        var hNewDesktop = CreateDesktop("My desktop", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, GENERIC_ALL, IntPtr.Zero);
        SwitchDesktop(hNewDesktop);

        var thread = new Thread( () => SecureDesktopThread(hNewDesktop) );
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        SwitchDesktop(hOldDesktop);
        CloseDesktop(hNewDesktop);
    }

    static void SecureDesktopThread(IntPtr hNewDesktop)
    {
        SetThreadDesktop(hNewDesktop);
        var win = new Window() { Content = "Hello World!", FontSize=30 };
        win.ShowDialog();
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
    }
}
```

So, why the different behaviour on Win7? Am I missing something here?

Comment: This seems like it's really more of a Win32 question than a C# or WPF question. You may get better answers if you come up with an unmanaged (e.g. C++) sample that does the same thing and post it under a more appropriate tag.

Comment: Just tried it using C++ and bare metal Win32 API (>200 lines of code): it works. Also tried it in Windows Forms, where it also works. So, it's definitely a WPF problem.

Comment: Perhaps. But you may find that the intersection of people using WPF and trying to do the above is limited. Now that you know that WPF is doing something different that native Win32 doesn't, you have a clue to lead you on further investigate. E.g. maybe this is a DirectX thing; my recollection is that WPF is build in DirectX, not GDI...if your native Win32 test used GDI, you're not going through the same code path that WPF would use.